Integration with respect to cdf.
Let $F$ be a continuous and strictly increasing CDF such that $F(x) \neq 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $U(x) = F^{-1}(1-\frac{1}{x})$.
The claim is that for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $z \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ bounded and continous functions, $a_n > 0$ and $b_n \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$n \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} z(\frac{x-b_n}{a_n}) F^{n-1} dF(x) = \int^n_0 z(\frac{U(\frac{n}{v}) - b_n}{a_n})(1-\frac{v}{n})^{n-1} dv$$.
I understand everything here except the sign. To be more precise, since we're doing the subsitution $F(x) = 1-\frac{v}{n}$, when $x = \infty$, we'd have $F(\infty) = 1 = 1-\frac{v}{n}$, so $v = 0$, and when $x = -\infty$, $F(-\infty) = 0 = 1- \frac{v}{n}$, so $v = n$.
Hence, should we not have
$$n \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} z(\frac{x-b_n}{a_n}) F^{n-1} dF(x) = \int^0_n z(\frac{U(\frac{n}{v}) - b_n}{a_n})(1-\frac{v}{n})^{n-1} dv = -\int^n_0 z(\frac{U(\frac{n}{v}) - b_n}{a_n})(1-\frac{v}{n})^{n-1} dv$$
?
Thank you

Your substitution is missing one detail:
$$F(x) = 1 - \frac vn \implies dF(x) = \color{red}{-}\, dv$$
